# Geom_label with fill aesthetic. Remove letter in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to remove the "a" letter that appears in `geom_label` legends when setting the fill aesthetic. Using `show.legend = F` removes the whole fill legend, and using `guides(text = 'none')` does not achieve any effect.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you also add code that you're using?

Comment: You could try adding theme(legend.text = element_blank())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I like to use is to add another geom layer with the same desired aesthetic (with alpha set to 0 so that it doesn't interfere with the resulting plot), so that the fill legend depends on that rather than the `geom_label` layer. Illustration below:

```
# instead of this
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, 
             aes(wt, mpg, fill = factor(cyl),
                 label = rownames(mtcars))) +
  geom_label()

# try this
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, 
       aes(wt, mpg, fill = factor(cyl),
           label = rownames(mtcars))) +
  geom_label(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_tile(alpha = 0) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

[image: plot]

(You can use a `geom_point` layer too, if you prefer point-shaped legend keys. Shapes 21-25 accept fill as an aesthetic.)

Comment: could you explain what `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))` does?

Comment: @Bakaburg It overrides the `alpha = 0` in `geom_tile()` & ensures the fill legend has visible colours. You can run the code without that line & compare the difference.